# Rebus: "a short document"

Tags: rebus

I was reading a rather short document, but the last part of it was missing. I think the document is supposed to finish with whatever this clue represents. Can you remind me what document I was reading?

[image: The puzzle. At left: a 3-by-3 grid. The grid has solid black circles in the middle-left, bottom-left, bottom-center, bottom-right, and middle-right positions, and an outlined black circle in the middle-center position. The top-center position has a blue star. At center: a dotted blue circle surrounding an image of a cube. The cube has a wavy free-form curve drawn below it; the curve starts at the bottom-left of the cube, curves around below, and then ends at the bottom-right of the cube. At right: a solid blue shape that looks like an upside-down capital Latin letter A.]

Comment: Welcome (back) to Puzzling! This is a pretty good rebus - I really enjoyed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first picture is

> a "liberty". In the game of Go, a liberty is a square that you can take to escape from having your group of pieces trapped. In this case, White can play there to avoid Black capturing his piece on the next move.

The second picture is

> "just ice".

The third picture is

> the mathematical symbol for "for all".

So the rebus is:

> "Liberty and Justice For All" - the phrase ending the American Pledge of Allegiance.